# mydaterangepicker angular4 how to bind with input field?

Tags: angular

I have used [mydaterangepicker](https://github.com/kekeh/mydaterangepicker) to show date picker calendar in form input in angular 4 project.

I have used below code in my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { IMyDrpOptions } from 'mydaterangepicker';
declare let jQuery: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'form-schedule',
  templateUrl: './form-schedule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-schedule.component.css']
})

  myDateRangePickerOptions: IMyDrpOptions = {
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    sunHighlight: false,
    showClearDateRangeBtn: false,
    editableDateRangeField: false
  };
```

**HTML**

```
   <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div>
                    <my-date-range-picker name="daterange" [options]="myDateRangePickerOptions"
                    [(ngModel)]="scheduleModel"  (dateRangeChanged)="onDateRangeChanged($event)"></my-date-range-picker>
            </div>

    </div>
```

Parent form in which date picker is shown:

End date should be greater than start date

I have simply used mydaterangepicker module to show datepicker field in form. but date picker appear on click of icon of calendar and not of input field.
I did not find any solution to change this configuration.

Need Help!

Comment: Did you try with this property `openSelectorOnInputClick` ?

Comment: Pawel :) It Worked. I don't know how I missed it. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property `openSelectorOnInputClick` to enable edit on input field click.